# Internationalization in Angular 8 by choosing an option in application itself

Tags: angular8

How to internationalize the content in my application by choosing the language from dropdown-list or buttons click in angular 8?

Comment: Have you tried anything or you are facing any issue/error, share your code if you have written any.

Comment: Visit https://angular.io/guide/i18n.

Comment: I have followed this https://alligator.io/angular/internationalization/. So, was able to get this working in this form but in this, we can see content in different locale on running different commands.  I want to change language of content just by clicking on the button or choosing an option from dropdown-list I go through many such searches but couldn't found a way